# Version 3.0 alternative for YouTube 2.0 API playlist

Tags: youtube-api

We did have this playlist. It is great because using this info we can show a latest video on YouTube.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/africawoodgrow/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published

How do we receive the same information from the new 3.0 API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is register for an API key -- you can do this by creating a project at console.developers.google.com, setting the YouTube data API to "on," and creating a public access key.

Once you have your API key, you'll need to get the channel ID you're interested in (rather than the username). If you don't know the channel ID, you can get it this way:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={username}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Once you have the channel ID, you can get those videos with the search endpoint, like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId={channel id here}&maxResults=25&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

There are also a lot of other parameters you can use to retrieve videos; see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list for more details.